# how to prove the convergence for this?

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis

What will be the best criterion to use to investigate convergence of the series (i do not need step by step explaination)

$$
\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{(2n-1)\sqrt{\log(4n+1)}}{n(n+1)}
$$

converge or diverge?

Comment: Oops! After the last edition the question looks pretty different from what it did some second ago !

Comment: I think the OP has to jump in: is that denominator $\;n(n+1)\;$ part of the logarithmic argument or not?! And I doubt it is as it appears now: for $\;n\;$ big enough that square root isn't even defined as then the logarithm is negative.

Comment: @Timbuc: I guess not since in this form the logarithm is negative for large $n$. Rolling back.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Exactly my point. Bad editing, I guess...but very bad original post.

Answer (score 1):

The series diverges simply because for any $n$ large enough
$$ \frac{(2n-1)\sqrt{\log(4n+1)}}{n(n+1)} \geq \frac{1}{n}.$$

Comment: For $n=1$ the statement that $s_n \geq \frac{1}{n}$ is false. However, you can say that the series diverges because for all $n$

Comment: @MarkFischler: all right, now fixed.

Answer (score 0):

In this case you can split the fraction into $s_n = \frac{\sqrt{2\log (4n +1)}}{n+1}$ and $t_n = \frac{\sqrt{\log (4n+1)}}{n(n+1)}$, with $\sum_n s_n \to_n \infty$ and $\sum_n t_n \to a< \infty$ - if both sums tended to infinity, you couldn't do that, since $\infty - \infty$ doesn't exist.

Both sums are monotone decreasing $\forall n>n_0$, so you can compare them to the corresponding integrals or (as Jack D'Aurizio) compare to the well-known sums that diverge/converge.